# How to prevent installing new apps from playstore? However there should be option for updating apps

Tags: android, google-play-services, device

How to prevent new apps installation in android device from play store? I want to give limited apps on their phone however those apps can be updated from play store, but I want to prevent new apps installation.

It's my clients need, as he'll provide customized devices to their clients. (Rooted already.)

Comment: what do you mean by **customized devices?**

Comment: customized means only those apps he'll give to their clients which he wants .

Comment: actually you can not restrict new apps installation from play store on devices but you can stop updating apps.it is not possible to control user or clients mind...if you want to do that anyway you have to make the android device specially or just tell the user or client that don't install new app from play store .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

As @brahmy adigopula said, you cannot restrict someone to download or install apps on device. However, I found this [similar thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144448/how-can-i-prevent-installation-of-new-applications-on-an-android-5-1-device-but) which might help.

> There are multiple approaches you could take:
>
> - a [kiosk-mode](/questions/tagged/kiosk-mode) solution. That would pin the user to a certain app or group of apps defined as "kiosk"
> - [parental-control](/questions/tagged/parental-control) apps, which are often a specific variant of kiosk
> - use an [App-Locker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_applocker)
>
> The latter most likely is the approach best fitting your current case:
>   You can define which apps should be "locked down" and which not.
>   Locking e.g. settings and the Playstore app, while
>   [unknown-sources](/questions/tagged/unknown-sources) are disabled, would prevent any new
>   installations. With auto-updates enabled in the Playstore app, these
>   would still be applied automatically.

Note that, to prevent installations via the Google Play web interface, the user ***must not*** have the credentials of any Google account linked to the device (no chance otherwise).

Hope this helps!